# back-button doesn't work properly ionic famework

Tags: ionic-framework, back-button

I have this flow in my ionic app... login.html page(which is a "ion-view")->side-menu page(side-menu from ionic framework)->page2.html page(which is a "ion-view"). Now i want to implement "ion-nav-bar" with "ion-nav-back-button" in it. Normally when i want to go back from page2.html the app should sent me to side-menu page....instead, my app, sent me to login page. Seems like side-menu does not have "ion-view" in it and it is not recorded in app flow.  Any suggestion how can i solve that ? thank you

Answer (score 0):

There is no a state for side menu, you can not 'go back' to open side menu.

In the normal, for the login view, you should disable the state temporally. Then the app will not 'go back' to login view. You can do it like this:

```
$scope.doLogin = function () {
        Auth.login($scope.loginData, function () {
            console.log('login success');
            $ionicHistory.nextViewOptions({
                disableBack: true
            });
            $state.go('home');
        });
    };
```

And you can also clear the view history of ionic to avoid going back with:

```
$ionicHistory.clearHistory();
$state.go('user.home');
```